# Padding in wxStyledTextControl, no clumpiness

Tags: python, wxpython, scintilla

i am trying to achieve a second margin into my wxpython code editor like so

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULdf2.png

and i would like a bit of padding above the code so the code isnt so close to the roof of the sizer.

i am currently left with this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQpRc.png

i got the idea of the second margin from notepad ++

there is no code on line 1 because i am indicating that there should be padding there, even thought the code would start on line 1, respectively.

i am still a beginner i python....

The question i am asking is, what method or style would i need to implement to achieve such a thing?

I have done my research on the demos and docs and yellowbrain, none which provide padding examples.

please help me out, thankyou.

code thus far, just incase:

http://pastebin.com/FxZgzuZp

Comment: it? what it are you talking about?

the whole stc is in a sizer, but that doesnt help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StyledTextCtrl does this out of the box.  Here are a few screenshots from the wxPython demo.

[image]

[image]

Or do I misunderstand.  Aren't the marking between the line numbers and the text area what you're looking for?

Comment: i didnt know that, weird.

how would i implement the second picture you provided?

Comment: It's a bit involved because you need to define the space, put in handlers, etc.  It's probably easiest just to look in the demo (Morewindows/Controls | StyledTextCtrl_2) and then search for a useful keyword, like "fold".

Comment: thats okay, i have found an alternative... how would i change the line number colors and not the text colors?

self.text = wxstyledtextctrl(panel)
self.text.SetForegroundColor() didnt work for me.. and if it did im pretty sure it would change the text color too, how could i differentiate the two?